# clion change default cache directory

Tags: clion, jetbrains-ide

Currently, for linux operating systems, the cache and index folders for clion are defaulted to /home/.Clion12/. I am on an NFS and want the cache directory and indexing directories to point to my internal ssd. Where can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer to this. In the bin directory where clion.sh is kept, there is an ideas.properties file. You can change the default location there.

Answer (score 0):

As @StevenCombs said, the file `idea.properties` is in the same bin directory where `clion.sh` is found, and the variable is `idea.system.path`.

I set it up like this. First, on the command line I did:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/mlakata
sudo chown mlakata /var/cache/mlakata
```

And then in the `${clioninstall}/bin/idea.properties` file, I added

```
idea.system.path=/var/cache/mlakata/CLion/system
```

CLion appears to populate the `CLion/system` directories under my personal cache directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved for me after I have created an idea.properties file in ~/.Clion2019.2/config then populated it with:

```
# custom CLion properties
idea.config.path=/someFolder/my_work/clion_ws/.Clion2019.2/caches/trunk-config
idea.system.path=/someFolder/my_work/clion_ws/.Clion2019.2/caches/trunk-system
idea.plugins.path=/someFolder/my_work/clion_ws/.Clion2019.2/caches/trunk-plugins
```

After this, the cache is build in /someFolder, not flooding my home folder anymore.

[Official support page for path parameters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/tuning-the-ide.html)